Сколько раз считается выражение PostgreSQL?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, сколько раз физически посчитается выражение t.col + 1 в этом запросе?
select t.col + 1 as first, 
       t.col + 1 as second,
       case
           when t.col + 1 = 10
               then X
           when t.col + 1 = 20
               then Y
       end as caseVal
from table


Во-первых непонятно, как это вообще узнать. Это детали реализации движка БД. Может он кэширует такие вещи, а может и нет. Единственное что можно сказать - что t.col тут будет видимо одинаковое для одной записи в БД при любом уровне изоляции транзакций.

@CrazyElf , потому и любопытно, что непонятно - как узнать :)

Если очень хочется узнать, то нужно читать исходники движка БД )

psql (18devel)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# select pg_backend_pid();
 pg_backend_pid 
----------------
           8799
(1 row)

postgres=# with t as (select 1 as col, 5 as x, 6 as y) 
   select t.col + 1 as first,
       t.col + 1 as second,
       case                   
           when t.col + 1 = 10
               then X
           when t.col + 1 = 20
               then Y
       end as caseVal
from t;
 first | second | caseval 
-------+--------+---------
     2 |      2 |        
(1 row)

gdb -p 8799

(gdb) break int4pl
Breakpoint 1 at 0x556c1f530651: file ../../../../src/include/postgres.h, line 204.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, int4pl (fcinfo=0x556c1ffacba0) at int.c:794
794     int32       result;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, int4pl (fcinfo=0x556c1ffacba0) at int.c:794
794     int32       result;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, int4pl (fcinfo=0x556c1ffacba0) at int.c:794
794     int32       result;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, int4pl (fcinfo=0x556c1ffacba0) at int.c:794
794     int32       result;
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Четыре раза при col != 9, при col = 9 - три раза.

спасибо! Очень любопытно: 1. Что будет если  t.col + 1 засунуть в cte/from и обращаться к алиасу? Всё равно вычисления каждый раз? 2. Что за дебажные шаманства используются?

Выражение выполнится три раза.

Выражение t.col + 1 вычисляется один раз для вычисления значения столбца first.
Выражение t.col + 1 вычисляется еще раз для вычисления значения столбца second.
Выражение t.col + 1 вычисляется третий раз в условном операторе case.


Подскажите, если я определю CTE/подзапрос во from, где будет считаться t.col + 1 as val, При дальнейшем обращении к val оно также будет считаться каждый раз "на лету" или это будет иметь место переиспользование результатов?
